# Why is the server returning 3 SYN + ACK packets during a SYN scan?

Tags: tcp

When you do a SYN scan against a opened TCP port (not filtered by Firewall), the server normally returns 3 SYN + ACK packets.

So, why 3 of that?

The target server is a Linux machine if relevanted to this question, and the scanner in use is NMAP.

Comment: Is there any time delay between each SYNACK? I'm thinking your implementation could be 'retrying' after a timeout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The normal [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) three-way handshake consists in a SYN from client to server, then a ACK+SYN from server to client, then an ACK from client to server. However, TCP has been designed to provide reliable data transport over a medium which is *not* reliable: stand-alone IP packets can get lost, damaged, duplicated, or transmitted out-of-order. That's why TCP is needed in the first place.

A server who has received a SYN responds with a ACK+SYN, and then *expects* an ACK as response. However, the server is well aware that packets can get lost, including its own ACK+SYN. So the server sends the ACK+SYN, then waits... and if it does not receive the final ACK from the client, the server assumes that its ACK+SYN might have been lost, so it emits it again. And again. Until the ACK from the client is received (which will not happen when the client is not a true client, but a port scanner which only sends SYN), or the server loses interest and gives up.

Each given operating system is responsible for deciding when, and how many times, a SYN or SYN+ACK or ACK will be repeated. On a Linux system, see the special files in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/` called `tcp_syn_retries` and `tcp_synack_retries`: they contain the number of times the kernel would emit SYN (respectively SYN+ACK) on a given connection attempt when being a client (respectively server). On a 3.2.0 kernel, I see that both files contain "5", meaning that a server subject to a port scan will emit **five** SYN+ACK packets. If you observe only three, then maybe your particular server was configured that way (this is as simple as `echo 3 > tcp_synack_retries`). Or maybe the server still uses the default value of 5, but your detection system was not patient enough: successive retransmissions use exponential delays, so the last retries can take a substantial number of seconds before being retransmitted.

Note that, to be able to retransmit SYN+ACK packets, the server must necessarily allocate a bit of RAM for that connection attempt, in order to *remember* this particular proto-client and retransmit the SYN+ACK. Abusing this allocation is the basis of the [SYN flood attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood). Lowering the maximum number of retransmission will make the server more robust against such attacks. In the extreme case, [SYN cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies) are a way for the server to *not* remember anything; as a consequence, when a server uses SYN cookies, it will respond with only a single SYN+ACK upon an incoming SYN. Since you observe that the particular server you are scanning sends the SYN+ACK several times, then you have demonstrated that this server does not employ SYN cookies, and is thus potentially vulnerable to SYN floods.

Comment: Doesn't nmap's SYN scan send RST packets immediately after receiving the first SYN+ACK?